# PHPMailer on Godaddy server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Below is my code it works fine on XAMPP Server. When I load same to the Godaddy server it gives an error **Class 'PHPMailer' not found in**

I have loaded all PHPmailer files on godaddy server.

```
<?php
$email_from = "something@gmail.com";
$from = "Name";

include_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Send mail using gmail

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "something@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = "password"; // GMAIL password
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $from);
?>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not basing your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer? Your code has some basic problems that would have been avoided by using that. Also, search for GoDaddy SMTP issues on here - beyond your path problem, GoDaddy is well known for blocking outbound SMTP, as the PHPMailer docs will tell you in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is coming from this line not finding/importing the PHPMailer class file:

```
include_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

This definitely sounds like a [pathing issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Are your directory paths all correct?  That is, this PHP code -- is it running from a directory with PHPMailer directory in the same location?  And if you're manually putting the files on your server, is your PHPMailerAutoload.php finding the PHPMailer class itself?

Comment: Indeed - and don't use `include` if your code can't work without the file you're loading; use `require` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your email must be send through godaddy servers, and also disable all security features, username, and password:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

You should view the PPMailer Troubleshooting https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#godaddy